# Trouble with a decimal to hexadecimal function that doesn't return anything

Tags: c

When I compile this nothing returns and it is just empty space where I can type, but nothing happens instead of computing the program, Any reasons why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void decimalToHex(long int decValue);

int main()
{
    long int decValue = 20;
    decimalToHex(decValue);

    return 0;
}

void decimalToHex(long int decValue)
{
    long int remainder,quotient;
    int i=1,j,temp;
    char hexadecimalNumber[100];
    quotient = decValue;
    while(quotient!=0)
    {
        temp = quotient % 16;
        if( temp < 10)
        temp =temp + 48;
        else
        {
            temp = temp + 55;
            hexadecimalNumber[i++]= temp;
            quotient = quotient / 16;
        }
    }
    printf("Equivalent hexadecimal value of decimal number %ld: ",decValue);
    for(j = i -1 ; j> 0; j--)
    printf("%c",hexadecimalNumber[j]);
    printf("\nGoodbye!\n");
}
```

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your code in a debugger and step thru it line by line to see exactly what it is doing. Surely you can find out more than just the fact that it is not working. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: As seems almost universal in these questions, there is no decimal here at all, other than in the source code. `long int decValue` is already in binary. Your method converts, or should convert, binary to hex.

Comment: Try the value 254 instead of 20, maybe that will give you a clue to the problem

Comment: So I'm going to be contrarian and upvote this question. The question is trivial. There are no defects in this question, and while not quite exemplary it shows someone trying to ask right.

Comment: @Joshua You don't consider the misdescription as decimal to hex a defect?

Comment: @user207421: With no reflection of said misconception of the code as written, no. Just poor English. Besides, we don't actually know from the question as written that he's not running on a decimal machine.

Comment: @Joshua We know he's using a `long int`, which is binary.

Comment: You really need to drop all those "magic numbers". `'0'` instead of 48. `'7'` instead of 55. Wait, `'7'`? Oh a bug, which is hidden to the programmer by the use of magic numbers. You probably meant 65, which should be written in as `'A'`.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm pretty sure 55 is correct; I'm used to seeing it written as 'A' - 10.

Comment: @Joshua That makes sense, perhaps... though strictly speaking you can't do arithmetic on letter characters, C only guarantees that it can be done on digits. There's absolutely no reason to write naive conversions like this anyway. Proper code is using the LUT version along the lines of `hexstr[i] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[value];`. Branch-free and no poorly-defined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            hexadecimalNumber[i++]= temp;
            quotient = quotient / 16;
```

Hmm shouldn't this be outside the else? Yes it should.

```
while(quotient!=0)
```

While we're at it, this should be a do/while loop not a while loop. Always go around the loop once.